# NSDateFormatter to parse TimeZone from multiple locales

Tags: macos, nsdateformatter

Any suggestions on how to parse date strings from older files using CET, and PDT style time zone from multiple locales? The file can be parsed in any locale and seems to mix formats for locales and includes both US and European 3 alpha time zones (CET, PST, etc).

I create the formatter like so:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-M-d h:m:s a zzz];
```

If I set the GB Local on it I get null for strings with US Time zones. And if I set nothing (Im in US) I get US time zones but not the European ones. Any thoughts on a solution?

Comment: You should be careful because those three character timezone codes are not unique. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations. It’s much safer if you can use ISO 8601/RFC 3339 formats (where time is generally represented in Zulu/GMT/UTC and bears the `Z` designator) or a format where the offset is explicit (e.g. `-0800` or `-08:00`). Are you stuck with this CET/PST format?

Comment: Yes, it's not my file or my preference for a format but I still have to parse it.

Comment: Then you might need two formatters, one in each locale (or one formatter and toggle its `locale`). Sorry.